# Why do I have a "HD" in my bootcamp screen and not macOS or similar

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, dual-boot

I have a MacBook 12 with Big Sur. I have also a Bootcamp installation with Microsoft Windows 10. When I open the bootmenu I have the following screen:

I don’t know why this label HD shows instead of macOS or similar. Selecting that icon starts MacOS with a differently named disk on the desktop and OS.

[image]

How can I change this label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon label is stored in the APFS volume `Preboot` in the same container as Big Sur.

The steps to change the icon label for Big Sur (macOS 11.1) is given below. Some of the steps are unique to Big Sur. Therefore, the steps may need to be adapted before being applied to previous versions of macOS.

1. While booted to Big Sur, get the name of the startup disk. From the menu bar, select ``→`About This Mac`. A popup similar to the one shown below will appear. In this example, the name of the startup disk is `MyBigSur`.

   [image]
2. Next, you will need to boot to built-in macOS Recovery for Big Sur.

   - **For Mac computers with an Intel processor:**
     From the menu bar, select ``→`Restart…`.
     Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key immediately after your Mac begins to restart.
     Keep holding until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear.
     If your Mac is using a firmware password, you're prompted to enter the password.
     Press the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination.
     If requested, enter the password for an administrator account.
   - **For Mac computers with Apple silicon:**
     From the menu bar, select ``→`Shut Down…`.
     Press and hold the power button on your Mac until you see “Loading startup options.”
     Select `Options`, then select `Continue`.
     If requested, enter the password for an administrator account.
3. From the menu bar select `Utilities`→`Terminal`. A Terminal application window will appear.
4. Enter a command whose output can be used to determine the APFS container identifier and the APFS volume group UUID for the startup disk. Below is the command used in this example.

   > Note: Replace name `MyBigSur` with your own value.

   ```
   diskutil info MyBigSur | grep -e Group -e "APFS Container"
   ```

   Below is the example output. From the output, the identifier and UUID can be determined to be `disk1` and `99740195-F728-458E-85A4-2E42A7932CB4`, respectively.

   ```
      APFS Container:            disk1
      APFS Volume Group:         99740195-F728-458E-85A4-2E42A7932CB4
   ```
5. Enter a command whose output can be used to determine the identifier for APFS volume with the name `Preboot`. Below is the command used in this example.

   > Note: Replace identifier `disk1` with your own value.

   ```
   diskutil list disk1 | grep Preboot
   ```

   Below is the example output. From the output, the identifier can be determined to be `disk1s2`.

   ```
              2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 297.6 MB   disk1s2
   ```
6. Enter a command to mount the APFS volume with the name `Preboot`. Below is the command used in this example.

   > Note: Replace identifier `disk1s2` with your own value.

   ```
   diskutil mount disk1s2
   ```

   Below is example output.

   ```
   Volume Preboot on disk1s2 mounted
   ```
7. Enter the commands that will change the icon label. Below are the commands used in this example to change the icon label to `macOS 11.1`.

   > Note: Replace directory `99740195-F728-458E-85A4-2E42A7932CB4` and icon label `macOS 11.1` with your APFS volume group UUID and desired icon label, respectively.

   ```
   cd /Volumes/Preboot/99740195-F728-458E-85A4-2E42A7932CB4/System/Libary/CoreServices/
   bless --folder . --label "macOS 11.1"
   echo -n "macOS 11.1" > .disk_label.contentDetails
   chown :wheel .disk_label*
   ```
8. From the menu bar, select ``→`Restart` to restart the Mac.

### References

[Mac computers with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211814)
[Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)
[Use macOS Recovery on an Intel-based Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/11.0/mac/11.0)
[Use macOS Recovery on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/11.0/mac/11.0)